# What is the difference between the heavens (shamayim) in Genesis 1:1 and the heavens (shamayin) in Jeremiah 10:11?

Tags: genesis

> Genesis 1:1 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.

the heavens
הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם (haš·šā·ma·yim)
Article | Noun - masculine plural
Strong's Hebrew 8064: Heaven, sky

> Jeremiah 10:11 "Tell them this: 'These gods, who did not make the heavens and the earth, will perish from the earth and from under the heavens.'"

heavens
שְׁמַיָּ֖א (šə·may·yā)
Noun - masculine plural determinate
Strong's Hebrew 8065: The sky

Is there a difference?

Comment: Do you mean a difference other than Jer. 10:11 was written in Aramaic so 'heavens' gets a different Strong's Number?  Possibly of interest: "Why was Jer. 10:11 written in Aramaic?" -  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4940/why-is-jer-1011-written-in-aramaic

Comment: Where did you pull your Strong's information from?

Comment: https://biblehub.com/genesis/1-1.htm

Comment: @TonyChan - does the above answer work for your?

Comment: The quoted verse is the only one, in all of Jeremiah, written in Aramaic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jer. 10:11 is written in Aramaic. שְׁמַיָּא (*shemaya*) is the definite form of שְׁמַיִן (*shemayin*). שְׁמַיִן is cognate with the Hebrew שָׁמַיִם (*shamayim*). Both are translated into English as “heaven(s).” Biblehub obscures (not intentionally) the fact that שְׁמַיָּא is Aramaic; it takes a few mouse clicks to discover that information.

[image]

Blue Letter Bible, on the other hand, makes it evident that the word is Aramaic.

[image]

Also, you have to realize, Strong’s numbers are categorized as Strong’s Hebrew, where the Strong’s number is preceded by an “H,” and Strong’s Greek, where the number is preceded by a “G.” There is no separate categorization for Aramaic words. Rather, they are listed under Strong’s Hebrew (prefixed by an “H”).

Comment: How much of Jeremiah is in Aramaic ? (Rather than Google and risk faulty information, I am asking a source which I believe to be reliable.)

Comment: @NigelJ—99% certain it is just Jer. 10:11 in the Book of Jeremiah.